# Time the execution time of multiple commands

Tags: linux, time

Is there a way to time a series of commands in linux?

Perhaps something like this:

```
/usr/bin/time { ls; pwd; ls }
```

Comment: even without the `time` command this would fail as it needs the final `;` i.e. `{ ls ; pwd  ; ls ; }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try to wrap it in a shell command:

```
/usr/bin/time /bin/sh -c 'ls;pwd;ls'
```

Answer (score 42):

Using `time` use () to create a subshell for the commands you wish to time. The syntax would be:

```
time ( ls; pwd; ls )
```

If using `/usr/bin/time` then add the commands to a shell script (for example my.sh) and 
time the shell script-:

```
/usr/bin/time my.sh
```

Comment: This works with `time` but not with `/usr/bin/time`. Running the command you gave produces `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ls'`

Comment: Although the accepted answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46106/419658 works great, I still prefer this version because it makes the code much readable, instead of just being passed as a string to `sh -c`. Anyway, Can somebody please point a situation when one would be preferred over another?

Comment: I can see that this works on `bash` and `zsh`, but not on `sh` and `fish`. I guess this may answer your question as to whether we should prefer one or the other: portability.